# CSS not taking effect when the URL of the page changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some HTML pages that share a common CSS file. I have them in the header and import them in the page. Everything is good, but, I have to go back to one page carrying an ID, it doesn't work.

I have a page `detail.html`, but when I return a `detail/id` it just doesn't charge. It can't be a href error because in the other pages is charging. I guess I have to change something so it applies everywhere?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"> 
<head>

    <title>Historiales Médicos</title>

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Página home">
    <meta name="author" content="Lucas Mazariegos">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon2.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" type="text/css"> 
</head>
```

And the URL I am getting: detail/1_S0004-06142005000900012-1. The HTML is charging but not the CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by "charging" and what do you mean "it just doesn't charge"?

Comment: That the css doesn't apply. I see the page without a format. Without CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that your CSS file `href="css/estilo.css"` is in a location relative to the URL of the page.

If the page URL is `http://example.com/detail`, then the CSS file is located in the root directory of the web site.  Then when the URL changes to `http://example.com/detail/id` then the reference `css/estilo.css` is expected to be in directory location `/detail/id/estilo.css`.

I recommend that you place all of your global CSS in a root directory called "css", then your href would become `href=/css/estilo.css` which will not change as the URL of the page changes.

You should do the same for all of your static/common images and JavaScript files.

Typically images go into an `/img` directory and JavaScript files into a `/js` directory.

If the CSS files are already in `/css/` directory for the web site, then you need to convert the relative reference `css/estilo.css` to an absolute reference `/css/estilo.css` and do that for all of your CSS files.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/estilo.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: but i already have them in a directory. I have my htmls, then 3 folders for the css, img and JS

Comment: i have to say i am using bottle to redirect the pages, ¿can that influence? i am getting the html correct but it looks like the css doesn't appear when i redirect it

Comment: DId you try changing your HTML to `href="/css/estilo.css"`?  Did that have any effect?